# Is the potential matrix-element of the Schrödinger equation in 2D polar coordinates always real?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, scattering, s-matrix-theory

Assume we want to solve the Schrödinger equation in 2D polar coordinates for an anisotropic potential (in order to get K-matrix). using this separation wavefunction
$$
\Psi(r,\phi) = \sum_{j,m} \frac{\psi_{jm}(E,r)}{\sqrt{r}} \mathrm{e}^{i m \phi},
$$
Schrödinger's equation will be
$$
\Big[ \Big(\partial_r^2 - \frac{m^2-1/4}{2 r^2} + 2E \Big)\delta_{m,m'} - 2 V_{m m'}(r) \Big]\psi_{jm'}(E,r)=0,
$$
where the potential matrix-element is given by
$$
V_{m m'}(r) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \mathrm{e}^{i m \phi} V(r,\phi)\mathrm{e}^{-i m' \phi} \mathrm{d}\phi.
$$
Now the question is whether $V_{m m'}(r)$ is always **real**?

**EDIT**: or how to choose the phase of the wavefunction in such a way that the $\psi_{jm}(E,r)$ will be a real matrix?

In my case, it is for some potential not real, therefore the K-matrix in scattering theory is not real, which is wrong!

**Edit2:answer**

It depends on the basis set that we are chosen. If the basis set is real the potential matrix element will be real. Choosing a basis set does not affect the final answer,namely, S-Matrix or generating the final wavefunction or ...

Comment: You should be able to prove its reality properties yourself. What is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: the potential can be anything, and it vanished when $r \rightarrow \infty$. For some of them, the integration is complex. I tried different integration methods, but still it is complex. I was wondering whether it is always real from the physical point of view.